# Double loop in JQuery Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following Jquery code in my website,

```
    $("#nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        });

        var counter = 1;

        $('.plus').click(function(e) {

            if(counter <= 3){
            $('#nav-tabs').append('<a href="#tab' +</button></a></li>');
            } else { alert("Only 3 Tabs Allowed!")};

            $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab' + counter + '"></div>');
            if (counter <= 3) {
                counter++;
            } else {};


        $('.close').click(function(e) {

            var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
            $("#tab" + panelId).remove();
            if(counter < 1){
                counter = 1
                }else if (counter >= 1) {
                    counter--;
                } else if (counter == 0) {
                    counter = 1
                };

        })

    });
```

My question is once i click .close instead of going once in the function, it again repeats itself an decrements my counter...

Comment: How many times is above code executed? If you apply a click handler multiple times, it will fire multiple times when click occurs.

Comment: Are you sure is is your actual code? There's a syntax error there. Also, there's no loop anywhere.

Comment: It just written in a single script file... Moreover, I have written the three functions in three different files, written inthree separate script tags, but the result remains the same.

Comment: Addition function is fine; only the .close fires once, then only repeats itself not the entire script... i have dry run it using firebug

Comment: Like @Juhana has said, there is a syntax error here - you're missing (at least) a closing brace for the `.$('.plus').click()` call. If this *somehow* runs, then every time you click `.plus`, you're adding a new click handle to `.close` as well, and that may be the reason why it duplicates.

Comment: `$(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");` can you plz put light on this.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan Thanx mate, i am going to try that now... will let you guys know if it works...

Comment: @Jai It removes the containing LI and sets panelId to the value of its `aria-controls` attribute.

Comment: `$('#nav-tabs').append('<a href="#tab' +</button></a></li>');` this line have issues.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work, i just wanted only 3 tabs, but as i remove the tabs using .close it removes once then keeps on repeating counter times....:p
i.e if i remove tab2 then it decrements counter 2 times making it goto 1 o sometimes zero, giving me incremental 4 or 5 tabs addition

Comment: Okay i have even tried return and exit() to terminate the script once it runs, but it still iterates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of actually binding click events to identify close/open was clicked. Try doing this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 1;

$("#nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function() {
    var item = $(this); // the anchor tag which was clicked

    item.tab('show');

    if( item.hasClass("open") ) { // checks if the clicked anchor tag has class "open"

        if(counter <= 3)
            $('#nav-tabs').append('<a href="#tab">Button</a></li>');
        else
            alert("Only 3 Tabs Allowed!");

        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab' + counter + '"></div>');

        if (counter <= 3)
            counter++;
    }

    else if( item.hasClass("close") ) { // checks if the clicked anchor tag has class "close"
        var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");

        $("#tab" + panelId).remove();

        if(counter < 1)
           counter = 1
        else if (counter >= 1)
            counter--;
        else if (counter == 0) {
            counter = 1
    }

    return false; //this will prevent default behavior
});

});
```

Comment: Can anyone Solve this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907997/show-dynamically-added-navlinks-when-added-in-bootstrap-navbar